# Difference between Open/SaveFileDialog classes and their use in a WPF form

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Quite curious, but was just wondering if anyone knows the difference between using:

System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog (in Assembly System.Windows.Forms.dll) and Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog(in Assembly PresentationFramework.dll)?

I use the PresentationFramework.dll version within the WPF form, but am currently re-using some old code in the form which includes showing the  System.Windows.Forms.dll version and wondering if:

1. there is a subtle difference between their appearance?
2. any interoperability issues with using the System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog? Or are both these just win32 dialogs anyway?
3. is this just to do with using Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog has [issues](http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=119) in windows vista?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a better explanation (might be out of date/irrelevant for later versions of .NET):

http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2008/04/12/vistas-savefiledialog-and-openfiledialog-in-wpf/

---

While they essentially do the same thing...they're different wrappers...around the WIN32 functionality.

- [Does WPF have a native file dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482486/does-wpf-have-a-native-file-dialog)
- http://rpelepei.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/using-open-file-dialog-window-in-wpf.html (see Why Bother Using the Win32 Version?)

However, there are a number of potential bugs in the WPF (`Microsoft.Win32`) version of the `SaveFileDialog`.

- http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=119
- [SaveFileDialog bug in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875056/savefiledialog-bug-in-wpf)
- [WPF Open FIle Dialog theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437598/wpf-open-file-dialog-theme)
- http://learnwpf.com/post/2007/01/05/Why-does-the-OpenFileDialog-in-WPF-look-so-e2809c1999e2809d-and-how-can-I-fix-it.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/wpf/thread/03b4e9d8-4039-4e67-bf2d-5d41f65376cb

How to extend WPF Open/Save Dialogs:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42008/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-Using-WPF

If you want more updated versions of the "Common" file dialogs (e.g. Windows 7 style ones) you can use the "Windows API Code Pack" (some of this has been rolled into .NET 4):

- http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack

So, which one you choose depends on your needs....if you aren't doing any customizations then you could get away with the Windows.Forms one.

Note using the Windows.Forms one will bloat your application a bit with an extra DLL.

Comment: Thanks - that's very useful. I have so far found no problems with using both types through my WPF form, and I don't need to worry about Vista, so looks like I am immune to most of the issues.

Comment: I really recommend the Windows API Code Pack. Try it out for the features. (For example, the TaskDialog. Why is WPF's MessageBox.Show so ugly compared to Windows Vista/7/8?)

Comment: Is this answer still up to date?